# process substitution with <(gunzip ...) fails

Tags: gzip, process-substitution

The following code returns: syntax error near `(`

```
#!/bin/bash
myprogram -i <(gunzip -c file.gz) -j <(gunzip -c file2.gz)
```

It seems it doesn't like brackets. How can I make this script work? If I run the same command for a Linux shell it works. It is when I try to run the script with the command inside that it fails. Do I need to protect brackets or so ??

The exact command line that works outside the script (command line) is:

```
 kaiju -z 1 -a greedy -m 5 -s 70 -x \
   -t /db/kaiju/nodes.dmp -f /db/kaiju/kaiju_db_nr_euk.fmi \
   -i <(gunzip -c files/mapped_reads_to_extracted_marker_genes/1/1.1.1.bin.13.genes.fa.R1.fq.gz) \
   -j <(gunzip -c files/mapped_reads_to_extracted_marker_genes/1/1.1.1.bin.13.genes.fa.R2.fq.gz)
```

Sorry for long line (kaiju is open source program for bioinformatics). Inside a script it fails with the error above

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

The way I'm running the script is `./script.sh` or `bash script.sh`. I have run `chmod +x` on the script also. Any idea how it should written then?

Comment: How exactly are you running the script?

Comment: specifically, if you are using `sh /path/to/script`, you're not using `bash`, and `<(something)` is a bashism.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Let's just call it a modernism of many current shells apart from some strictly POSIX-compliant shells.

Comment: What's your version of bash? (`bash --version`) What system does it fail on? Are you sure that the error comes from this shell script and not from within `myprogram`?

Comment: What is the error you get?